# Как сделать задержку на нажатие кнопки? JS

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать так, чтобы событие, срабатывающее при нажатии клавиши Пробел, не срабатывало, если я нажимаю на клавишу чаще 1 раза в секунду.

```
document.onkeypress = function (event) {
    let key = event.keyCode || event.charCodel;
     if (event.key == ' ') {
            shootUp(0);
     }
     }
```

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно узнать про setTimeout/setInterval.

Comment: Вы знаете, зачем слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы расположен знак "галочка"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let timer;
document.onkeypress = function(event) {
  if (!timer && event.key == ' ') {
    console.log(0);
    timer = setTimeout(() => timer = clearTimeout(timer), 1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let lastSpacePress;
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.key === " ") {
    if (lastSpacePress > Date.now() - 1000) {
      return;
    }
    lastSpacePress = Date.now();

    console.log("SPACE HIT");
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const sleep=(ms)=>new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, ms));

let spc = true;
document.onkeypress=async({keyCode})=>{
    if(spc === true && keyCode === 32){
        spc = false;
        await sleep(1000);
        console.log('space hit');
        shootUp(0);
        spc = true;
    }
};
```

Нормальный код принятого ответа

```js
let timer;
document.onkeypress=({keyCode})=>{
    if(!timer && keyCode === 32){
        console.log(0);
        timer = setTimeout(()=>(timer = clearTimeout(timer)), 1000);
    }
};
```